# How to deploy bot framework v3 bot in azure?

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to deploy a bot developed using node.js in v3 of bot framework. Earlier, there was an option to choose between v3 and v4 of template. Now, it is not showing this option. How to deploy the v3 bot?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The V3 SDK is being retired with final long-term support ending on December 31st, 2019. We highly recommend that you start migrating your V3 bots to V4.  Here is the migration [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-javascript?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

But you still can deploy your v3 bot to Azure.

1.[Create a Bot Channels Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

2.[Deploy your bot to Azure service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs). Remember to update the bot with consistent microsoft_app_id and microsoft_app_password.